# MENU with help of ncurses library

Tags: c

Hello everybody,
                I had edited a example code given according to myself.It has 2 menu with same options and i want to change the options of both the menu and when any of the option is selected,it must be printed on the message bar,but i am unable to do so.
I am facing 2 problems.
i) Unable to change the options of 2 menus.
ii) The selected item is not printed on the message bar.

Need help.Below is the code edited by me from the link 
www.linuxfocus.org/English/March2002/article233.shtml
t

and here is my code.

```
#include <curses.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ENTER 10
#define ESCAPE 27
void init_curses()
{
        initscr();
        start_color();
        init_pair(1,COLOR_WHITE,COLOR_BLUE);
        init_pair(2,COLOR_BLUE,COLOR_WHITE);
        init_pair(3,COLOR_RED,COLOR_WHITE);
        curs_set(0);
        noecho();
        keypad(stdscr,TRUE);
}
void draw_menubar(WINDOW *menubar)
{
        wbkgd(menubar,COLOR_PAIR(2));
        waddstr(menubar,"PARALLEL");
        wattron(menubar,COLOR_PAIR(3));
        waddstr(menubar,"CON.");
        wattroff(menubar,COLOR_PAIR(3));
        wmove(menubar,0,20);
        waddstr(menubar,"SERIAL");
        wattron(menubar,COLOR_PAIR(3));
        waddstr(menubar,"CON.");
        wattroff(menubar,COLOR_PAIR(3));
}
WINDOW **draw_menu(int start_col)
{

        WINDOW **items;
        items=(WINDOW **)malloc(9*sizeof(WINDOW *));

        items[0]=newwin(10,19,1,start_col);
        wbkgd(items[0],COLOR_PAIR(2));
        box(items[0],ACS_VLINE,ACS_HLINE);
        items[1]=subwin(items[0],1,17,2,start_col+1);
wprintw(items[1],"Shailendra singh",1);
        items[2]=subwin(items[0],1,17,3,start_col+1);
wprintw(items[2],"THIVNENT TECH",2);
        items[3]=subwin(items[0],1,17,4,start_col+1);
wprintw(items[3],"THINCLIENT",3);
        items[4]=subwin(items[0],1,17,5,start_col+1);
wprintw(items[4],"SOLARCOMPUTING",4);
        items[5]=subwin(items[0],1,17,6,start_col+1);
wprintw(items[5],"TECHNOCRATS",5);
        items[6]=subwin(items[0],1,17,7,start_col+1);
wprintw(items[6],"SENSORS",6);
        items[7]=subwin(items[0],1,17,8,start_col+1);
wprintw(items[7],"NCURSESLIB",7);
        items[8]=subwin(items[0],1,17,9,start_col+1);
wprintw(items[8],"GCC COMPILER",8);





        wbkgd(items[1],COLOR_PAIR(1));
        wrefresh(items[0]);
        return items;
}
void delete_menu(WINDOW **items,int count)
{
        int i;
        for (i=0;i<count;i++)
                delwin(items[i]);
        free(items);
}
int scroll_menu(WINDOW **items,int count,int menu_start_col)
{
        int key;
        int selected=0;
        while (1) {
                key=getch();
                if (key==KEY_DOWN || key==KEY_UP) {
                        wbkgd(items[selected+1],COLOR_PAIR(2));
                        wnoutrefresh(items[selected+1]);
                        if (key==KEY_DOWN) {
                                selected=(selected+1) % count;
                        } else {
                                selected=(selected+count-1) % count;
                        }
                        wbkgd(items[selected+1],COLOR_PAIR(1));
                        wnoutrefresh(items[selected+1]);
                        doupdate();
                } else if (key==KEY_LEFT || key==KEY_RIGHT) {
                        delete_menu(items,count+1);
                        touchwin(stdscr);
                        refresh();
                        items=draw_menu(20-menu_start_col);
                        return scroll_menu(items,8,20-menu_start_col);
                } else if (key==ESCAPE) {
                        return -1;
                } else if (key==ENTER) {
                        return selected;
                }
        }
}
int main()
{
    int key;
    WINDOW *menubar,*messagebar;

    init_curses();

    bkgd(COLOR_PAIR(1));
    menubar=subwin(stdscr,1,80,0,0);
    messagebar=subwin(stdscr,1,79,23,1);
    draw_menubar(menubar);
    move(2,1);
    printw("Press F1 or F2 to open the menus. ");
    printw("ESC quits.");
    refresh();

    do {
        int selected_item;
        WINDOW **menu_items;
        key=getch();
        werase(messagebar);
        wrefresh(messagebar);
        if (key==KEY_F(1)) {
            menu_items=draw_menu(0);
            selected_item=scroll_menu(menu_items,8,0);
            delete_menu(menu_items,9);
            if (selected_item<0)
                wprintw(messagebar,"You haven't selected any item.");
            else if(selected_item=1)
                wprintw(messagebar,"You have selected menu SHAILENDRA SINGH.",1);
            else if(selected_item=2)
                wprintw(messagebar,"You have selected menu THINVENT TECH.",2);
            else if(selected_item=3)
                wprintw(messagebar,"You have selected menu THINCLIENT.",3);
            else if(selected_item=4)
                wprintw(messagebar,"You have selected menu SOLAR COMPUTING",4);
            else if(selected_item=5)
                wprintw(messagebar,"You have selected menu TECHNOCRATS.",5);
            else if(selected_item=6)
                wprintw(messagebar,"You have selected menu SENSORS.",6);
            else if(selected_item=7)
                wprintw(messagebar,"You have selected menu NCURSESLIB.",7);
            else if(selected_item=8)
                wprintw(messagebar,"You have selected menu GCCCOMPILER.",8);


            touchwin(stdscr);
            refresh();
        } 
        }
    while (key!=ESCAPE);

    delwin(menubar);
    delwin(messagebar);
    endwin();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

the problem is with `else if(selected_item=1)` it should be `else if(selected_item == 1)`. This is a common mistake that is hard to debug. And one more problem with the code is that it is displaying the previous menu than the one selected. Hope you can fix it:)

Comment: Hello Sakthi, well thanks for the reply.Ya it was a mistake which is hard to find.Actually i am new to C as well as to ncurses.In my code,i had used refresh(),than why it is not displaying the second menu under SERIALCON.I had again edited the code and make new options.if you can explain a  bit more.i had created one more WINDOW **draw_menu1(int start_col) for the second menu but unable to understand it and that what creating problem for me.If you can provide a tutorail link.i had read a lot from net but unable to understand.

Comment: If you are using Linux, you can go through the man pages of the functions. Regret that I could not post any link right now. I am also new to ncurses. If I would find anything interesting I will surely let you know.